# DropDownList populate method affects postback behaviour?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've started to rewrite code in an existing project and changed the way how two `dropdownlists` are populated. When using `DataBind` the `SelectedValue`has the correct value in the `Page_Load` after a postback. But when using `AddRange` the `SelectedValue` is always the first value in the dropdownlist.

How can the way how the dropdownlists are filled affect the postback behaviour? Yes, there are java scripts in the page also, but I can't see how they could interfere with this.

The way that works (`SelectedValue` is correct in `Page_Load`):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IList<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
    list.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Site.OriginalStructure, "0"));
    list.Add(new ListItem("5", "5"));
    list.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));
    list.Add(new ListItem("15", "15"));
    list.Add(new ListItem("20", "20"));
    list.Add(new ListItem("25", "25"));

    DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

    DropDownList2.DataSource = list;
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Text";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Value";
    DropDownList2.DataBind();   
}
```

The way that doesn't work (`SelectedValue` is always the first value in ddl in `Page_Load`):

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var numberQuestionsPerPageDdlValues = new[]
    {
        new ListItem(Resources.Site.OriginalStructure, "0"),
        new ListItem("5", "5"),
        new ListItem("10", "10"),
        new ListItem("15", "15"),
        new ListItem("20", "20"),
        new ListItem("25", "25")
    };
    DropDownList1.Items.AddRange(numberQuestionsPerPageDdlValues);
    DropDownList2.Items.AddRange(numberQuestionsPerPageDdlValues);
}
```

Comment: What means _"correct SelectedValue"_ since you nowhere set the `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue`. You are not even using the [constructor of `ListItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ec0w4405.aspx) which takes a third argument `enabled` which would mean selected in a DropDownList.

Comment: With _"correct SelectedValue"_ I mean the value that is selected by the user on the page. When I tested it I selected the value "5". I don't think I have to set the `SelectedIndex` --> [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.selectedindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): _"The default value is 0, which selects the first item in the list."_

Comment: In `Page_Load` I can see that `Request.Form[DropDownList1.UniqueId]` contains the selected value, but the `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` is `""`.

Comment: Can you show also the aspx markup of the DropDownList?

Answer (score 1):

> With "correct SelectedValue" I mean the value that is selected by the
>   user on the page

You are binding the `DropDownList` to it's DataSource on every postback. You should do that only `if(!Page.IsPostBack)`. Otherwise events will not be triggered and the `SelectedValue` of the user will be overridden.

I would also suggest to use `page_load` instead.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        IList<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>();
        list.Add(new ListItem(Resources.Site.OriginalStructure, "0"));
        list.Add(new ListItem("5", "5"));
        list.Add(new ListItem("10", "10"));
        list.Add(new ListItem("15", "15"));
        list.Add(new ListItem("20", "20"));
        list.Add(new ListItem("25", "25"));

        DropDownList1.DataSource = list;
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Text";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Value";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        DropDownList2.DataSource = list;
        DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Text";
        DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Value";
        DropDownList2.DataBind(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: I've tried that as well for both of the populating methods but then neither work.